# Securing rest api with CAS and using single sign on with existing web app

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have two applications, a standard java/spring web app and a spring rest api (in reality, I have several rest apis, some of which are ideal for sharing across several web apps, but that doesn't change the example). When a user logs into the webapp, I want them to be able to seamlessly also make ajax calls (GET and POST) to the rest api, which is also secured with CAS.

So far it seems like the suggested approach for this is to get a proxy granting ticket in the webapp, and use it to generate a ticket that could be used to call the rest api. This however means that ajax calls made from the client page have to be proxied through the web app.

Are there any other means available to make this happen without the proxy through the webapp? Not all the rest endpoints are secured (some are meant to be public) and I realize I can cut down on the use of the proxy by directly using the rest api for those, but still, it feels heavy having to double the processing for the other requests.

One idea I had, which I don't know if it's possible, is instead of proxying through the webapp, what if the webapp could return the proxy ticket to client, and then the ajax calls could me made with that? Seems like that's not recommended though-

Comment: Did you find solution? I need the same now, secure rest api with cas and access it from other application.

Comment: I have implemented the proxy granting ticket setup as a fall back for when rest calls fail. However, most of the time, the calls work just fine, I load a secured 1 pixel image from the rest api, after the user has logged into the primary app, this initiates a login to the rest api.

Comment: I had same problem and I added jsessionId that returns from server to my rest api requests(I put it in cookie) and every thing worked great!